# XElement - not able to capture the next node

Tags: c#, xml, linq, linq-to-xml

I have a below xml file:

```
        <?xml version='1.0'?>
                <Products>
                <Product>
                  <Product_id>1100</Product_id>
                  <Product_name>xyz</Product_name>                       
               </Product>
               <Product>
                  <Product_id>1101</Product_id>
                  <Product_name>abc</Product_name>                       
               </Product><Product>
                  <Product_id>1102</Product_id>
                  <Product_name>def</Product_name>                       
               </Product>
               </Products>
```

I am trying to get the values of each attribute but I only get on value and not all 3 of them.Any pointers on how to correct this?

```
foreach (XElement xe in xdoc.Descendants().Elements("Product"))
            {

                obj.status = xe.Element("Product_id"). Value;
                obj.file_id = xe.Element("Product_name").Value;
                productlist.Add(obj);

            }
```

This above loop does not traverse through all the attributes except for the first product "xyz".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create a new object for each loop.  Right now you are only saving the last item

```
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            List<Object> productlist = new List<Object>();

            foreach (XElement xe in xdoc.Descendants().Elements("Product"))
            {
                Object obj = new Object();
                obj.status = xe.Element("Product_id").Value;
                obj.file_id = xe.Element("Product_name").Value;
                productlist.Add(obj);

            }
        }
    }
    public class Object
    {
        public string status { get; set; }
        public string file_id { get; set; }
    }
```